# How to get the same id as the web store hosted extension when packaging it in local?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a extension hosted on chrome web store, and I host it on my own server too.
But they can't have the same id, so users can install both of them.

So, when I pakage my extension, how can I get a id that is same with the extension hosted on chrome web store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just download CRX file from the Gallery and upload it to your server? I see no need in repackaging it manually.

Comment: This is a good idea.I didn't think about it.And it works.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The webstore usually signs with its own key, which will result in a different extension ID than your hosted version, but there's an undocumented way of telling the webstore to sign with your own key. See this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/3vvygtEajMQ

Comment: So I can't export key from web store.But this works.Thanks a lot.